# Lotus notes - refering to a doc. from a NotesDocumentCollection

Tags: object, view, lotus-notes

I have a view which on top there is a button called `Delete`

I want to delete all the selected documents from the view; for this I used:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim database As NotesDatabase
Dim documentCollection As NotesDocumentCollection

Set database=session.CurrentDatabase
Set documentCollection=database.UnprocessedDocuments


If documentCollection.Count=0 Then
    Msgbox "No documents selected ",,"warning"
Else 

    userChoice=Msgbox ("Delete" & Cstr(documentCollection.Count) & " documents?",64+100, _
    "Confirm...")   

If userChoice=6 Then
    Call documentCollection.RemoveAll(True)
            Call workspace.ViewRefresh
End if
```

But, what if I want to delete only some docs ( from all selected docs. from view ) which have let say `Value = YES` where `Value` is a text field inside the document?

I tried declaring:

```
    Dim ui As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set doc=ui.document
```

But I get the message: `Object variable not set`. So I guess I have to refer to a document using the NotesDocumentCollection? How?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Error Message has nothing to do with your question... The Error Message comes from setting doc form an unitialized uidoc. You need to have a `Set ui = ws.CurrentDocument`somewhere in your code, and of course declare ws: `Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace`

But for your question you don't need an ui- document at all. To delete just some of the selected documents, you cycle through the collection and delete just the documents that match your criteria:

```
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim nextDoc as NotesDocument
Set doc = documentCollection.GetFirstDocument()
While not doc is Nothing
  Set nextDoc = documentCollection.GetNextDocument(doc)
  if doc.GetItemValue( "Value" )(0) = "Yes" then
    call doc.Remove(True)
  end if
  Set doc = nextDoc
Wend
```

Or you reduce the collection to just contain the documents that match your criteria and then delete the whole collection:

```
Call documentCollection.FTSearch("[Value] = Yes",0)
Call documentCollection.RemoveAll()
```

But take care: The collection is reduced with a FTSearch, that might also get "Yes of course" or "Ye" depending on the setting of the FT Index of the database -> Not very reliable.

Comment: I would recommend not using doc.Value to reference the field, instead use doc.GetItemValue("Value")(0)...
Also, doc.Value would return a variant, so that line should read If doc.Value(0)="Yes" Then...

Comment: SHAME ON ME! Usually I never use the direct access... and of course it has to be (0)... Corrected this in my answer. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the documents in the document collection and then process them individually. Here's an example loop that uses your documentCollection variable:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set doc = documentCollection.GetFirstDocument
While Not(doc Is Nothing)
    ' Do stuff

    ' Get next document
    Set doc = documentCollection.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

Comment: Take care: if "do stuff" means deleting the document, then your line with GetNextDocument will possibly fail with an "Object Variable not set"... That's the reason for the "nextDoc" in my example...

Comment: Ah yes, good point, Torsten. I somehow missed that MFG Flay wants to delete documents and not just process/update them.